# Change the front page basing on the domain

Tags: 8

I need to write a custom module to map some static pages used as front page to some specific domains. For example,

- If domain is www.abc.com, the front page should be static_page_1
- If the domain is www.bcd.com, the front page should be static_page_2

I have made a form for administrator users to enter the domain name and the static page they want as front page, but now I don't have any idea on where and how to write the code for detecting the domain name and set the front page.
Any information and suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) or looked at their code?

Comment: @leymannx my supervisor doesn't allow me to install a module. he suggest me to find a hook or search about event subscriber. I check Domain Access code on its gitHub but cant find about the set homepage part. is it still possible to do this without Domain Access module?

Comment: Frontpage is a config setting, take a look at the extra module `domain_config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already find the answer by referring to [Programmatically set the front page per site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274126/programmatically-set-the-front-page-per-site). It is much simpler than the reference, because I just want to map the domain with my static page and I don't have a multisite drupal.
So, I just add an event subscriber and put all the mapping there.

> In the getSubscribedEvents method you need to set the weight to something greater than 30 which overrides the Page Cache and Dynamic Cache.

```
$events['kernel.request'] = ['kernel_request', '35'];
```

> Add this function in the same event subscriber file

```
public function kernel_request(Event $event) {
$config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.site');
$site_path = \Drupal::service('site.path');
$site_path = explode('/', $site_path);
$site_name = $site_path[1];

if ($site_name === 'site2' && $event->getRequest()->getPathInfo() == '/') {
  $config->set('page.front', '/node/239')->save();
}
else {
  $config->set('page.front', '/home-content')->save();

}
}
```